# Yu-gi-oh cards' effect

Tags: c++

I'm building a simple c++ platform for a yu-gi-oh duel but I found a problem with card effects. Since almost every card has a different effect this means that I have to write a different function every card. 
Is there any way you can think to make this easier or do I have to write a function for every card of the game?y

Comment: I guess you have to go down that road.

Comment: Please give examples of the effects and the functions you're thinking of creating?

Comment: You probably want to learn object oriented programming, so you can use inheritance: make one 'parent' card and then make children cards

Comment: I'd recommend scripting the cards separately in a DSL.

Comment: The peril of starting programming with games are the hard problems you face. What @R.MartinhoFernandes proposes is the only sane option, but will require some skill to be cleanly executed.

Comment: Ideally you should be writing as much data and as little code as possible. Break the effects into related groups codes those up in their general forms, and hang data off of the cards that indicates which groups are present and provides the argument to them. Then you always process the data and run the indicated functions with the supplied argument. Mini-languages for the win.

Comment: BTW--Your question is in danger of being closed as too wide open, unspecific and unsupported by detail to be given a good answer. The edit button is under your post on the left hand side. This may be fixable (even if the question is closed, reopening *is* possible). This is also the most likely reason for the downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what, you have to *implement* every single effect one way or another. Placing them into different functions, or even different classes, helps you organize code. Think of function headers as of inline reminders to self: "here starts the implementation of this particular chunk".

In other words, don't save on functions. You'll thank yourself later on.

Placing all effects into one giant function is possible in theory, but it won't be "easier" in any meaningful sense, especially not in the long run.

And read some book about programming in general. StackOverflow is not a school. "Code Complete" by Steve McConnell (ISBN 1556154844) is good.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for design patterns. I'm not too familiar with yu-gi-oh but I'm sure you can achieve what you want. These approaches would require you to use some good ol' Object Oriented programming. Here are some starting patterns that may help you out:

The strategy pattern (Find common types of "card effects" like damage or trap etc and extend the functionality):
http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy/cpp/1

The decorator pattern (If an effect will do many different things, where some of the effects are similar to other "card effects", you can use the decorator pattern to combine a damage effect from another card with a sleep effect that get's applied with this card etc.): 
http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator

Either way it will be very hard to learn either of these patterns from any online source. I would recommend going out and picking up a good design patterns book if this sounds like something you're interested in. Unfortunately I don't have any good suggestions for a design pattern book for c++.